# Совет по базе данных (нагрузки)

Tags: highload, база-данных, php, сервер, mysql

Будет сайт, где пользователи смогут создавать свои категории. Пользователей ~ 10 000. Категорий у одного ~ 5-20. Планирую всего категорий около 150 000.

Вопрос:

- Какую базу данных выбрать? Работал
     только с MySql.
- Если MySql то какой тип таблиц?

Думаю сделать 2 таблицы типа

- **1 таблица**: id, name, url, option,
     option2
- **2 таблица**: id, user_id, cat_id

Буду искать по 2 таблице нужные id и делать выборку с 1 таблицы только нужных.
Но незнаю есть ли смысл в этом....

Если есть - дайте просто советы по работе с таким количеством данных. Не работал с базой большей за 7000-10000 записей.

Боюсь большого упадка производительности...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цифры небольшие, страшного ничего не случиться. Можете смело использовать JOINы, Innodb и MySQL. Только убедитесь, что у Вас правильно [поставлены индексы](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/06/09/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD/).